# Я новичок в swift, помогите справиться с такой задачей

Tags: swift, tuple

```
var x = [(1, «x»), (4, «y»), (6, «a»)]
```

Массив из кортежей - возвести Int в квадрат, отфильтровать только четный Int и упорядочить по строкам по возрастанию. Используем map, filter, sorted.
Можно составить все функции в одну цепочку, например:

```
x.map { рассчет }.filter { рассчет }.sorted { рассчет }
```

Comment: Максим, чтобы добавить код, нужно перед ним и в конце добавить 3 знака: ```

Comment: Как пробовали решить?

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь это поможет:

```
var result = x.map({($0.0*$0.0, $0.1)}).filter({$0.0 % 2 == 0}).sorted(by: {$0.1<$1.1})
```